# How does GitHub's Audit Log assign locations for different events?

Tags: github, geolocation

I'm reading a book^1 which is describing GitHub's Organizations feature.  About Audit Logs, it says,

> You can go to the 'Audit Log' tab and see what events have happened at an organization level, who did them and where in the world they were done.

See screenshot [here](http://imageshack.com/a/img922/10/ahwzkD.jpg).  From the screenshot, why exactly is the GitHub Audit Log reporting that those particular events occurred in France?  Is it because those events came from IP addresses that can be geolocated to France?  Or is it because those events were initiated by a GitHub user whose profile indicates he is from France?  Or something else?

---

^1 [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked GitHub support, and they confirmed the location is from IP address geolocation.  They also confirmed there is currently no way to disable this, either by the contributor or the repo maintainer.